# Recovering lost text which was copy pasted from a website to MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, website, clipboard, blogging

I have been working on a blog post (non- English - Tamil) for a more than a week now. Because of how https://www.blogger.com/ autosave function works, my latest draft accidentally got deleted and before I hit the undo button the empty post got autosaved. I searched online and found many people have faced this issue and there is no way to recover this from Blogger as it was still a draft version and not published (although I previewed the post a few times, not sure that will help me to recover the text). Luckily (not sure entirely!), a few days ago I copied the post and pasted in word just to check the number of words, but I didn't save the word file (I know that was stupid!). I only opened the word file for less than a minute and closed it without saving.

From my extensive Google search, I think the following are the only possible(?) ways of recovery.

1. Recover the unsaved word file - even though I didn't save the word file I found out that MS Word saves unsaved files (.asd files) in `C:\Users\"my_user_name"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles` for up to four days. To confirm this, I opened a word document and wrote some random stuff and closed it in less than a minute without saving it. The recovery file (.asd) was indeed located inside the above-mentioned folder. But I can't find the recovery of my word file in which I copy-pasted my blog post. I think it's because it was more than 4 days ago. I also checked my recycle bin, but can't find any .asd files there. Is there any way I can find the .asd recovery file of my unsaved word file which was created more than 4 days ago? I am using Word from `Microsoft 365 Apps for  enterprise`.

2. Recover from clipboard - Since I copy-pasted the text I thought maybe there is a way to recover from the clipboard. I found out there is indeed an option in `Windows 10` to recover text from the clipboard. but unfortunately, this option on my computer was disabled until I found out about it. So, that is no longer an option unless anybody here knows another way to recover from the clipboard.

3. Recover from .dmp file - I created a dump file for the page where I lost my text. But I can't seem to find my long non-English text. I tried to search using some keywords which I used regularly in my texts (these are English words, although the majority of the post is non-English)), but the search returns null. I think I must have gone back and forth in the page before I found out about this option, so not sure if the .dmp file will have the history before, say 4-5 steps. Also, since the text is mainly non-English I don't know how the non-English words are saved in .dmp files and if they can be recovered. Any suggestion?

4. I used Google input tool to type the text as it's a non-English blog post. (https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/). But every time once it reaches a certain length I cut-paste into my blog, so I don't have the full text in this tool. Is there any way to recover the history from this tool?

Finally, is there any other way to recover the text?

Sorry for the long post and sorry if some of the above options were unclear. I tried to provide as much as information possible on my attempts. I am a bit desperate to recover the text as it's my 10 days work (I know I should have saved it somewhere else, I was just being stupid and was completely relying on Blogger. A lesson learned in a hard way though!)